# Log file upload/deletion actions on amazon s3 via the management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

Is it possible to log when an upload or deletion of a file happens in s3 via the management console? From what I can tell, CloudTrail allows object level logging of events via API calls, as well as a few management console actions, like signing in to the console. But I can't figure out how to log uploads/deletes via the console.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable S3 Access Logs:

1. Go to Amazon S3 console.
2. Select your bucket.
3. Click on the Properties tab.
4. Click on Server access logging.
5. Enter the name of the bucket to store the logs in. This must be different than the bucket that you are tracking. Optionally enter a target prefix.

[Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try and then accept the answer if it works.

Comment: will it take some time for s3 bucket to reflect any logs generated in specified s3 log bucket?

Comment: @sri - please create a new question.